# Custom action not working in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've created a custom action in woocommerce in order to rewrite the breadcrumbs function and put it in another place into html, but it didn't work.

Firstly, I removed the original Woocommerce breadcrumb:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
```

After, I added a custom action in my theme functions.php:

```
add_action('woo_breadcrumbs', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
```

And my custom function for breadcrumbs:

```
function woocommerce_breadcrumb( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', array(
        'delimiter'   => ' &#47; ',
        'wrap_before' => '<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" ' . ( is_single() ? 'itemprop="breadcrumb"' : '' ) . '>',
        'wrap_after'  => '</nav>',
        'before'      => '',
        'after'       => '',
        'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    wc_get_template( 'global/breadcrumb.php', $args );
}
```

Finally, I put this on my header.php:

```
<?php do_action('woo_breadcrumbs'); ?>
```

I have no idea what could be wrong here. Any help??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your call to remove_action() has too many parameters.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Also, your call to add_action() is set to allow 0 parameters but your woocommerce_breadcrumb() definition expects one so you need to fix that mismatch.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

I haven't run the code locally but those are the only issues I'm seeing. I hope that helps solve the problem.

SIDE NOTE: For my own peace of mind I like to give my functions unique names, rather than reusing the name of a function I'm overriding. Not all software developers wrap their definitions in function_exists() checks so I try to err on the side of caution there. WooCommerce does use functions_exists() checks so you're safe with that approach here.